# header("Location:"); breaking with .htaccess setup

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file in my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Which is removing .php extensions in the URL (eg. www.example.com/about or www.example.com/about/, yet still loading the page (www.example.com/about.php). The only change I've needed to make to my HTML so far is to include a `../` infront of every `href` or `src`.

Now I have come to use the following code at the end of a PHP login script:

```
header("Location: ../dashboard/");
```

Which should take me to www.example.com/dashboard.php but instead throws the following error:

```
The requested URL /example.com/dashboard.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The file is definitely uploaded. Is there any issue with my .htaccess which is causing the `header()` to behave incorrectly?

**EDIT**

If I change the line to this:

```
header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
```

then it works, but I *really* don't want the file extension in the URL.

Comment: Does `/example.com/dashboard.php` exist?

Comment: It does, yes. Check edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was a simple user mistake.

The directory I was working from wasn't *truly* the root directory. It was a parked domain within the same account hosting. so I was actually in `root/example.com/dashboard.php` whereas the .htaccess file was in `root/.htaccess`. Making a copy of the .htaccess file in to `root/example.com/` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your rules to check for existence of `.php` file before rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And then for your header redirect, simply do this:

```
header("location: ../dashboard")
```

Without the end trailing slash (/).